# 2012 - Occurrence in form does not match database occurrence

Tags: uniface

I am new to uniface after adding a simple sql statement to a legacy screen in uniface 9 getting the error below, can someone tell me what this error means and how can we find root cause of this issue.

**2012 - Occurrence in form does not match database occurrence.**

Thanks,

Comment: below error is found on debugging "ERROR=-10·;
MNEM=<UIOSERR_LOCK_DATA_MISMATCH>·;
DESCRIPTION=Lock, data mismatch·;
COMPONENT=XYZ0231·;
PROCNAME=CP_MORE·;
TRIGGER=DTLF·;
LINE=8"

Answer (score 0):

This implies that the SQL statement has modified the database record (or something else outside of the current screen). It is normal for uniface to automatically detect such a mismatch and catch/report the condition. You could then re-retrieve the record or handle some other way. I must say however that you should avoid using the direct SQL statement and allow Uniface to manage dbms interaction. Is there a specific reason you have used the SQL statement? Take a look at selectdb. It is not targeted at updates but can do many common things you do with the SQL statement.